# Performing calculation in SQL based on values given in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two temporary tables that I am extracting data from in a stored procedure

`#rtn` looks like

```
dt                     indx_nm          cusip_id        lrtn
2013-08-19 00:00:00.000 ABQI            33736Q104       -10.2
2013-08-16 00:00:00.000 ABQI            33736Q104       2.28
2013-08-15 00:00:00.000 ABQI            33736Q104      -18.38
2013-08-14 00:00:00.000 ABQI            33736Q104       -2.73
2013-08-13 00:00:00.000 ABQI            33736Q104       3.38
2013-08-12 00:00:00.000 ABQI            33736Q104       2.45
2013-08-19 00:00:00.000 ACNACTR         18385P101       -0.13
2013-08-16 00:00:00.000 ACNACTR         18385P101       -0.02
2013-08-15 00:00:00.000 ACNACTR         18385P101       -0.51
2013-08-14 00:00:00.000 ACNACTR         18385P101       -0.37
2013-08-13 00:00:00.000 ACNACTR         18385P101       5.2
2013-08-12 00:00:00.000 ACNACTR         18385P101       6.31
```

etc wuth alot more different `indx_nm` and `cusip_id`

`#rtn2` looks like

```
dt                      cusip_id    lrtn
2013-08-19 00:00:00.000 00162Q106   -0.00752860307693481
2013-08-16 00:00:00.000 00162Q106   -0.0131599903106689
2013-08-15 00:00:00.000 00162Q106   -0.0369237661361694
2013-08-14 00:00:00.000 00162Q106   -0.0315451622009277
2013-08-13 00:00:00.000 00162Q106   -0.0180829167366028
2013-08-12 00:00:00.000 00162Q106   -0.0140992403030396
2013-08-19 00:00:00.000 00162Q205   -0.00420033931732178
2013-08-16 00:00:00.000 00162Q205   -0.00409352779388428
2013-08-15 00:00:00.000 00162Q205   -0.023819625377655
2013-08-14 00:00:00.000 00162Q205   -0.0221214294433594
2013-08-13 00:00:00.000 00162Q205   -0.0169548392295837
2013-08-12 00:00:00.000 00162Q205   -0.00570738315582275
```

also with a lot more different `indx_nm` and `cusip_id`

my current code is:

```
    insert into etf_table (indx_nm, cusip_id, cor, dt_pnts)
    select a.indx_nm, b.cusip_id,
    (AVG(a.lrtn * b.lrtn) - AVG(a.lrtn)*AVG(b.lrtn))/ STDEVP(a.lrtn)/STDEVP(b.lrtn) cor, COUNT(*) dt_pnts
    from #rtn a, #rtn2 b
    where a.dt = b.dt and a.lrtn is not null and b.lrtn is not null
    group by a.indx_nm, b.cusip_id
    having  STDEVP(a.lrtn) > 0 and STDEVP(b.lrtn) > 0
    order by a.indx_nm, cor desc
```

however, i would like to only run `(AVG(a.lrtn * b.lrtn) - AVG(a.lrtn)*AVG(b.lrtn))/ STDEVP(a.lrtn)/STDEVP(b.lrtn)` in accordance with a table called `etf_data`

```
Ticker  CUSIP_ID    Indx
AADR    00768Y206   MXEA     
AAIT    46429B374   MSIAITNU 
AAXJ    464288182   NDUECAXJ 
ABCS    18383Q788   BKABCT
```

(lots more of `ticker`, `cusip_id` and `indx` obviously)

with the condition that: 
`indx_nm` in `#rtn` matches the `Indx` in this table and where the `cusip_id` in #rtn2 matches the `cusip_id` in this table along each row 
i.e. only perform `(AVG(a.lrtn * b.lrtn) - AVG(a.lrtn)*AVG(b.lrtn))/ STDEVP(a.lrtn)/STDEVP(b.lrtn)` for `cusip_id` = `00768Y206` and `indx` = `MXEA` and so forth
for each corresponding `cusip_id` and `indx` given in `etf_data`
 
 
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
INSERT INTO etf_table (indx_nm, cusip_id, cor, dt_pnts)
SELECT a.indx_nm, b.cusip_id, (AVG(a.lrtn * b.lrtn) - AVG(a.lrtn) * AVG(b.lrtn)) / STDEVP(a.lrtn) / STDEVP(b.lrtn) AS cor, COUNT(*) AS dt_pnts
FROM [#rtn] AS a
INNER JOIN [#rtn2] AS b ON a.dt = b.dt
INNER JOIN etf_data AS c ON a.indx_nm = c.Indx AND b.cusip_id = c.cusip.id
WHERE (a.lrtn IS NOT NULL) AND (b.lrtn IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY a.indx_nm, b.cusip_id
HAVING (STDEVP(a.lrtn) > 0) AND (STDEVP(b.lrtn) > 0)
ORDER BY a.indx_nm, cor DESC
```

Comment: thanks this works, however some `Indx` from `etf_data` correspond to multiple different `Ticker` so this causes them to be used twice in the `(AVG(a.lrtn * b.lrtn) - AVG(a.lrtn) * AVG(b.lrtn)) / STDEVP(a.lrtn) / STDEVP(b.lrtn)` calculation as reflected with a large number of dt_pnts. How can I it so each `ticker` corresponds with its individual  `Indx` minus repetition? @MontyWild thanks!